# Creating Image slider using only jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an image slider using ***Jquery***.

What I have is a main div with 3 sub divs with images.

Take a look at this fiddle. *[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N6Mzb/)*

Ok now i got the design just the way I want it. What is missing is the functionality.
When i hover over the div or the images, I want it to act like a clockwise slider.

This may look a bit confusing. Take a look at this demo. *This is what i want*.

[DEMO](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/RotatingImageSlider/)

*This is what i want*.The **right** div gets filled with the **middle** image src , the **middle** div gets the **left** div src. The **left** div get an **new** src from an *array* of images i have defined. Currently i can only change one image div at a time.

However I don't want to use any more *plugins*. Only **Jquery** plugin. A **CSS** only solution would be the best but I do not think it will be possible.

JQUERY

```
    $('.maindiv img').mouseover(function () {
        var image = this;
        loop = setInterval(function () {
            if (i < images.length - 1) {
                i++;
                $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
            } else {
                i = 0;
                $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
            }

        }, 1500);
```

**EDIT:** I managed to get one part of this working. [CHECK THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/N6Mzb/1/).Just need to add fade effect Now the problem is after the images in the array end the first images dont loop back... Had not thought of this before.Does Anybody know how i can get over this issue?

Comment: If there's already a script that works for you (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/RotatingImageSlider/), why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? Why not just taking a look at a javascript that is right there? I'm not saying "steal it", but take a look how they did it, or approach them - maybe they would like to seel you the script or right to this script.

Comment: @WTK Lets just say, I need a new set of wheels.

Comment: Long to recreate but possible. Need to play with the angles of the images per slide..

Comment: @msbodetti No No. The angles are fine. Its just the Jquery...

Comment: @AnaMaria No I mean that demo website you gave, they are using a plugin to play with the angles, they are using this plugin http://wiki.github.com/heygrady/transform/

Comment: @msbodetti I know. I just want to create something on my own.

Comment: @AnaMaria a nice challenge! Hope you get it right :)

Comment: Some anonymous downvoting. Nice... Any reasons why? No i guess or else you would have left a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mabye something like this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [];
    var loop;
    var i = 0;

    images[0] = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1GfA01TRDgrh-c5xWzrwSuiapiZ6b-yzDoS5JpmeVoB0ZCA87";
    images[1] = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQSyUWiS4UUhdP1Xz81I_sFG6QNAyxN7KLGLI0-RjroNcZ5-HLiw";
    images[2] = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_E_OgC6RiyFxKtw03NeWyelfRgJ3Ax3SnZZrufNkUe0nX3pjQ";

    $('img', '.maindiv').mouseover(function () {
        //Get divs inside main div and reverse them, so right is first
        var divs = $($('div','.maindiv').get().reverse());
        //Set up loop
        loop = setInterval(function(){
            divs.each(function(key, div){
                if (divs[key+1])
                {
                    //All divs gets image src from previous div > img
                    $('img', div).attr('src', $('img', $(divs[key+1])).attr('src'));
                }
                else
                {
                    //This is left div
                    if (images && images[i])
                    {
                        //If picture url not in array then add it
                        if ($.inArray($('img', div).attr('src'), images) == -1)
                        {
                            images.push($('img', div).attr('src'));
                        }
                        $('img', div).attr('src', images[i]);
                        i++;
                        if (i>= images.length) i = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 1500);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        clearInterval(loop);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFcQg/1/)

Comment: Works only once. it has to keep sliding when the mouse is hovered.

Comment: Check my edit. i managed to get the slider to work. but my first 3 images are getting destroyed. i need to save them and go back into the loop

Comment: @AnaMaria, Hei i made some changes on code, so now its on the loop, and allso checks if last image src is in images array, if not then it will be added into array end. Actually you could add them into array on document ready function so you would not need to check array on every loop turn. Allso added mouseout function to stop the loop. Actually it was not ment as full code at first.

Comment: Not exactly perfect, but il go with this solution as it is close to what i had in mind