# IE-11 has depreciated the time related features. What to use in place of t:seq in IE 11 to switch the images

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation

I am new to CSS.
I want to switch the images on screen using CSS.
Earlier i was using t:seq container to perform the same in Internet Explorar-8 but in Internet Explorar-11 it has been depreciated.
So my problem is if time related features has been depreciated in IE-11 then what to use in place of "t:seq" which i was using earlier to change the images in particular duration on screen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, what exactly you mean by "Switch the image on screen", do you want to create an image slider type feature?

Comment: swtiching image means..just want to show one image for 2 seconds then another image for next 2 seconds...etc.

Comment: This may be of interest, more specifically `transition-delay` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same functionality easily by using the `setInterval()`  function in JavaScript.

The Syntax is something like this

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 2000);
```

so it will call the defined function every 2 seconds.

Now there are more than one ways to side images inside divs to achieve the effect

an example will be something like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .animate({width: 'toggle'})
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 2000);
```

So in the above code we initially hide all the other elements inside our `#slideshow` container,except the first.

Then every 2 seconds we slide the current Image(using method given [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/)) and load the next image(by calling the `next()` function ) and fade the newly loaded image.

Is we reach the end we just repeat the procedure.

Here is the

### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/JEf4P/)

PS:

There are several JavaScript plugins also available to achieve your goal.Some of them are listed below

- [Menucool non jquery JavaScript Slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)
- [BxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) (jQuery based)

You might also want to check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946589/creating-image-slider-using-only-jquery)

Comment: Hi i am facing one problem...could you please help. the solution you provided works for below structure.. <div id="slideshow">
<div> <img src="m.jpg"> </div>
<div> <img src="9_m.jpg">  </div>
</div>..but in my case my structure is as below...................
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="m.jpg">
<img src="9_m.jpg">
</div> ...so my query is could you please suggest the solution when i don't have <div> tags for each and every image. but i have just one div tag on top of the list.

Comment: @MukulKashmira: you will just have to include the image height in the CSS, and will have to change the selector to `$('#slideshow > img:first')`.Here is a link to updated fiddle, hope you'll find it useful.
http://jsfiddle.net/64rkn/

Comment: @MukulKashmira : you can also add `opacity: 'toggle'` property to animate function to slightly enhance the effect.Here is a fiddle for that http://jsfiddle.net/64rkn/1/

Comment: @mukul . If the above answer solved your problem you can accept it,or if you are having some other issue you can just ask it here